# VBA copy word table to excel with bullet points

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have incorporated this code, which I got from an older post, in my script. The code goes through each table in a word document and inserts it in the excel file. The tables are put in the same sheet and one below the other. The problem is that the cells in the word tables contain bullet points and numbering which when moved to excel are completely lost. Is there any easy modification that I can do in order for the bullet points to transfer over? Thank you.

For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
With .tables(tableStart)

```
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
               
            Next iCol
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        Next iRow
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
Next tableStart
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use code like:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
```

to convert all auto-numbering etc. to actual text. Alternatively, you could limit it to specific tables, as in:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
```

Discard the changes when you're done.